# In next.js, how do I apply both a custom css class and a bootstrap class to an element

Tags: css, next.js

The css class is imported and then applied to the element as shown below;

```
import styles from "./Home.module.css";

<div className={(styles.collection, "card")}>
```

Individually they work but when applied as shown  above the styles are not applied to the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a template literal, including your dynamic class name via interpolation:

```
import styles from "./Home.module.css";

<div className={`${styles.collection} card`}>
```

Alternatively, use a helper like [`clsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx):

```
import c from 'clsx';
import styles from "./Home.module.css";

<div className={c(styles.collection, "card")}>
```